# Обновление Ubuntu по расписанию

Tags: ubuntu, обновление

Как в Ubuntu сделать обновление по расписанию? Или как осуществить, чтобы обновления закачивались на сервер, а потом по расписанию устанавливались на все машины с Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/руководство_по_ubuntu_server/управление_пакетами/automatic_updates

Comment: Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Answer (score 1):

Руководство по Ubuntu Server » Управление пакетами » [Автоматические обновления](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_ubuntu_server/%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/automatic_updates):

Пакет unattended-upgrades может использоваться для автоматической установки обновленных пакетов и может быть настроен обновлять все пакеты или только обновления безопасности. Для начала установите пакет, введя в терминале следующее:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
```

Для настройки unattended-upgrades отредактируйте `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` и поправьте следующее под ваши требования:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "Ubuntu precise-security";
//      "Ubuntu precise-updates";
};
```

Безусловно пакеты могут помещаться в «черный список» и, следовательно, не будут обновлены автоматически. Для блокирования обновления пакета добавьте его в список:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
//      "vim";
//      "libc6";
//      "libc6-dev";
//      "libc6-i686";
};
```

Чтобы разрешить автоматические обновления отредактируйте `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` и установите соответствующие опции настройки apt:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

Настройки, приведенные выше, обновляют список пакетов, загружают и устанавливают доступные обновления каждый день. Локальный архив загрузок чистится каждую неделю.

Результаты работы unattended-upgrades сохраняются в журнале /var/log/unattended-upgrades.
Уведомления

Настройка `Unattended-Upgrade::Mail` в файле `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` позволит unattended-upgrades посылать почтовые сообщения администратору с уточнением какие пакеты требуют обновления или имеют проблемы.

Другим полезным пакетом является apticron. Пакет apticron настраивает задачу cron для отправки почтовых сообщений администратору по любым пакетам в системе, для которых есть обновления, а также перечень изменений по каждому пакету.

Для установки пакета apticron введите в терминале:

```
sudo apt-get install apticron
```

Как только пакет установится, отредактируйте /etc/apticron/apticron.conf для установки почтового адреса и других опций:

```
EMAIL="root@example.com"
```